# Identity column in java db

Tags: java

Is there a way to add an identity column into java DB using netbeans.
the table is PAYMENTS
column name is ID

Comment: Geez, what's so hard looking this up in the manual where the ALTER TABLE statement is documente.

Comment: What your means of `Java DB`? Is your means `Derby`?

Answer (score 0):

First hit on google for 'java db identity':
http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/Derby-DML-Primary-Key-IDENTITY-Column.html

In other words use:

```
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

or

```
GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
```

As part of your primary key declaration.